# 301 HTTP Responses on Pelican static site generator

Tags: http, drupal, http-status-code-301, github-pages, pelican

I'm moving my blog from Drupal to Pelican and cleaning up some old URLs.

I now have several hundred old URLs that won't work and which should return 301 Moved Permanently responses. Is there a way for Pelican or Github Pages to handle these old locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, there's no way to do HTTP redirects from Pelican or Github pages, but you can do clever things using `meta refresh`.

My solution to this is thus to create a gazillion files that do meta refreshes, redirecting folks to the correct locations.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case. How did you set those up in Pelican—the only *good* idea I can think of is a custom template, but that falls down when changing the folder structure (I'm going from `yyyy/mm/slug` to `slug` on one site)…

Comment: For every old location I needed to redirect I created an HTML file that was just a meta redirect. Here's a live example: https://github.com/mlissner/michaeljaylissner.com/blob/master/content/blog/2010-donations/index.html

Comment: Thanks kindly! I'm about to do this for about 45 files… and I still need to think through how to handle the fact that I've changed the output structure. :-/